# Extract anchor after an Image then click that specific anchor using IMACROS

Tags: extract, imacros

I am looking to extract an anchor after an image then click on that specific anchor I extracted.

I am trying to extract the anchor tag after "img src="http:mydomain.com/img/tags.png"

HTML:

```
 <tr>
 <td align="right">50.</td>
 <td>
  <img src="http:mydomain.com/img/tags.png">
  <a href="/tag/dog/">
   <strong>#dog</strong>
  </a>
   <span style="color:#999;">(</span>
    <a title="" target="_blank" href="http://mydomain">+</a>
  <span style="color:#999;">)</span>
</td>
 <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
 </tr>
```

IMACROS:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 2
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://mydomain.com    
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

I am a complete noob at this, so I apologize on not knowing how to go about this...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract "/tag/dog/" when you can use:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=href
```

if you want to click on scraped link, you could use :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:{{!extract}}
```

Comment: I have multiple table rows and keep running into the issue of it clicking "a title="" target="_blank" href="http://mydomain">+</a"  I want to keep going on to the tag pos after like: TAG POS=1, TAG POS=2, TAG POS=3 and so on...

Comment: it should not click on <a title="" if you use my code, because it will click only on A  tag with href equal to scraped value